# Wrong result on 2017 MathCamp P1

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

> Lotta is a consulting mathematician who specializes in very large numbers. She runs a business with 100 clients ranked 1 through 100 in order of importance. (The most important client is ranked 1.) Each day, Lotta has time to visit only one of her clients.
>
> A client feels mistreated if Lotta has never visited them, or if Lotta has visited someone less important since the last time she visited them. Every day, Lotta visits the most important client that feels mistreated. On the first day, she visits client 1; on the second day, she visits client 2; on the third day, she goes back to client 1, and so on.
>
> When none of Lotta's clients feel mistreated, she can finally retire.

I want to know when will Lotta retire.
My first thought was a [recurrence](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41621958#41621958).
Let's say that Lotta takes $d_N$ days to make all $N$ clients happy. When with $N+1$ clients, she has to visit all the $N$ first clients before client $N+1$. By supposition, she'll take exact $d_N$ days. When all the first $N$ clients are happy, she'll meet client $N+1$, taking a whole day. The last client won't feel mistreated anymore - but all the other clients are not happy. Then she'll take $d_N$ more days to make all of the $N$ clients happy. So to make $N+1$ clients happy, she took $2d_N + 1$ days. So we have the recurrence $d_{N+1} = 2d_N + 1$, with $d_1$ = 1. Its general solution is $d_N = 2^N - 1$, so Lotta will take exact $2^{100} - 1$ days to retire. But the [official result](https://artofproblemsolving.com/school/mathjams-transcripts?id=438) is just $2^{100}$! What am I doing wrong? What is the case I'm not counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably down to the precise wording of the question - she will not have retired on day $2^{100}-1$ (she makes a visit that day) but will have retired on day $2^{100}$.

Comment: Jesus Christ. You're right.